# Save variable with alarm manager event

Tags: java, android, sqlite, alarmmanager

I'm building a study planner application for Android, i have the `AlarmManager` set up and working to trigger a notification when the time elapses, which works fine. 
When setting the alarm, the alarm details are saved into an `SQLite` database, when the alarm is set off, i need to recall the alarm information, is there some form of variable i can save into the database and link to the specific alarm so that i can use it in an `SQLite query` to find the correct entry.

UPDATE Code below:

```
Long nIdLong = System.currentTimeMillis();
        String nId = nIdLong.toString();
Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
                alarmIntent.putExtra("nID", nId);

                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,  alarmIntent , 0);

                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getActivity().getSystemService(getActivity().ALARM_SERVICE);
                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

AlarmReciever:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {
        long dbId = intent.getLongExtra("nID", 0);
        String notificationId = Long.toString(dbId);
Log.i("App", "called receiver method");
        try{
Toast.makeText(context, notificationId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're sending a String through the intent, it needs a Long, this code should work.

```
Long nIdLong = System.currentTimeMillis();
        String nId = nIdLong.toString();
Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
                alarmIntent.putExtra("nID", nIdLong);

                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0,  alarmIntent , 0);

                AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getActivity().getSystemService(getActivity().ALARM_SERVICE);
                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

While setting the alarm, first retrieve the id which will be created while inserting alarm details to SQLite via

```
long uniqueId = db.insert(your query);
```

And put that in the intent for PendindIntent for AlarmManager

```
Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(this, AlarmEventReceiver.class);
alarmIntent.putExtra("dbId", uniqueId); 

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,  alarmIntent , 0);
```

Inside the onReceive() of AlarmEventReceiver, you can get the id & retrieve the data from DB.

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    long dbId = intent.getLongExtra("dbId", 0);
}
```

Comment: How do i retrieve the value on the AlarmReveiver?

Comment: I tried this, however when more than one alarm is set it only pulls the information from the first one that was set, not the rest

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I found a different way of doing it, but i don't really like that way as it can get buggy, but I've added my code into the op :) this code always returns 0 however